# How to evaluate >9 number in a String expression Java

Tags: java, string

Life is very easy if the expression has values from 0 to 9 but

If expression = 23+52*5 is input by user then I take it in a String named expression.

Now what I want is that a new String or char Array in such a fashion that:

```
String s or char[] ch =  ['23','+','52','*','5']
```

**so that ch[0] or s.charAt(0) gives me 23 *and not 2*.**

To do so I have tried the following and am stuck on what to do next:

```
    for(int i=0;i<expression.length();i++)
        {       
            int operand = 0;
            while(i<expression.length() && sol.isOperand(expression.charAt(i))) {
                // For a number with more than one digits, as we are scanning 
                // from left to right. 
                // Everytime , we get a digit towards right, we can 
                // multiply current total in operand by 10 
                // and add the new digit. 
                operand = (operand*10) + (expression.charAt(i) - '0'); 
                i++;
            }
            // Finally, you will come out of while loop with i set to a non-numeric 
            // character or end of string decrement it because it will be
            // incremented in increment section of loop once again. 
            // We do not want to skip the non-numeric character by 
            // incrementing it twice. 
            i--;

         /**
         * I have the desired integer value but how to put it on a string 
         * or char array to fulfill my needs as stated above.
         **/
         // help or ideas for code here to get desired output

       }
```

In the while loop the method `isOperand(char)` is returning a boolean value true if char provided is `>=0` or `<=9`.

Comment: a very simple `split` using a regex that does not match digits would do.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `'23'`. The type `char` represents a *character* (disregarding Unicode supplementals at the moment). A digit is a character, which is why you can have something like `'2'`. But "23" can only be a number or a string, not a char.

Comment: @njzk2 That could be a solution. But I would really like to form a code of my own to get this too.

Comment: @RealSkeptic So can I get '23' at the first index of a string?

Comment: No, you can't. Because `charAt(int)` returns a single character. You can get `"23"` as the *substring* of a string, but you already have that. You can break your string into smaller *strings*, but if you break it into characters, you won't get what you want.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Breaking into smaller strings is a good idea to get my job done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to want a `String[]` when you break the expression apart.  Regex lookbehind/lookahead ([Java Pattern Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)) allows you to split a String and keep the delimiters.  In this case, your delimiters are the operands.  You can use a split pattern like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String expression = "23+52*5";
    String[] pieces = expression.split("(?<=\\+|-|\\*|/)|(?=\\+|-|\\*|/)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pieces));
}
```

Results:

```
[23, +, 52, *, 5]
```

One this to consider, is if your expression contains any spaces then you're going to want to remove them before splitting the expression apart.  Otherwise, the spaces will be included in the results.  To remove the spaces from the expression can be done with `String.replaceAll()` like this:

```
expression = expression.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

The "`\\s+`" is a regular expression pattern that means a whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r].  This statement replaces all whitespace characters with an empty space essentially removing them.

Comment: Great. It worked for me and even gave me an insight on how to do this on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Can you once explain me how the split() func. works. I tried looking online but could not get a good source explaining the kind of split you have done.

Comment: @RiddheshSanghvi It's not so much the split, but the regular expression pattern that is provided to the split.  This was a good reference for me http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Checked it. A great reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**try using a switch case:**

//read first character
switch data
if number : what is it ( 0,1,2,3...?)
save the number
if its an operator
save operator
** 2 the switch has 4 cases for operators and 10 for digits **

// read the next character
again switch
if its a number after a number add both chars into a string
if its an operator "close" the number string and convert it into an int

If you will need some code I will gladly help.
Hope the answer is useful.

```
for i = 1 ; i = string.length

 switch :

case 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 (if its a digit)
   x(char) = char(i)
case +,-,*,/ (operator)
   y(char) = char(i)
   x[1] + x[2] +...x[n] = X(string) // build all the digits saves before the       operator into 1 string
convert_to_int(X(string))
```

Comment: A pseudo code or a little more elaboration would be a great hep.

Answer (score 1):

```
String expr = "23+52*5";

String[] operands = expr.split("[^0-9]");
String[] operators = expr.split("[0-9]+");
```

This breaks it into:

[image: debugger info]

Comment: Just a note on terms: in the expression `2+5`, the `+` is the **operator**, and `2` and `5` are its left and right **operands**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
\d+
```

Will grab any instance of one or more consecutive digits.